# MS ACCESS - Tabluar sub report gaps

Tags: ms-access, report

I seem to have found an issue when producing a report with a subreport within it. In the subreport I have set the fields within the "details" heading to tabular and have set the margins & padding to 0cm. Is there a reason why this subreport is still applying vertical gaps between each row?
[image]

[image]

Comment: if it's a continuous form you also want to trim the height of the "detail" section.

Comment: Is your screenshot Print Preview or Report view? Please add a screenshot of Design view. -- Are any controls in detail section set to `Can grow` = Yes ?

Comment: print preview! and yes all the controls are grouped so that if one control grows then so do the others. this is needed in case fields are longer than others. added the design view in the Question...

Comment: Hmm, I can sort of reproduce this, though my gaps seem smaller. I don't think you can do anything about it. If it bothers you enough, you could change the design - get rid of the borders, and use Detail section `AlternateBackColor` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a small margin above/below the controls in the Detail section. Select the controls and set the Top property(this is not the same as the Top Margin and Top Padding, but actually the position) of these controls to zero(0). This will adjust the controls to the top of the Detail section. Drag the bottom of the Detail section towards the controls. This should eliminate the gap. Alternatively, after your set the Top property to zero, you can set the height of the controls to the height of the Detail section.

Also check if you have any grouping on each row with header/footer which could be the cause of the gap.

Comment: unfortunately I have done all of the above, made sure the controls where flush with the sections. Top was already set as 0, the height within the section is the same. and I believe there is no grouping connected to the headers and the controls.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set the border style to transparent. Then set the Gridline Style for top, bottom, left and right to 'Solid'. Now set the Gridline Color to Black. Also set the Gridline Width Top, Bottom, Left and Right to Hairline (or thicker if you want).

If you look at the image, the redlines are the gridlines. And the black lines are the borders of the text boxes. You can see that even though I tried moving the text boxes right next to each other, the grid still adds its own gap. So the solution is to hide your borders and just use the grid for the border.
  [image: gridlines vs borders]